# jQuery flashing effect button animation (fiddle provided)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, mobile

Please check out my fiddle.  Why does the flash effect only happen on the first click.  After that it does not flash anymore:

http://jsfiddle.net/vyAkk/

```
 $("#button").click(function (e) {
$(this).css('background', '#03182B').delay(500).queue(function(d) {
    $(this).css('background', '');
});
 });
```

Comment: interesting im curious to see the solution myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not dequeueing.

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    $(this).css('background', '#03182B').delay(500).queue(function(d) {
        $(this).css('background', '');
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vyAkk/8/)**

Comment: Thanks.  I was originally going to give the guy under me credit but yours is more proper.  It works with multiple levels.

Answer (score 3):

Something's getting mucked up in the event queue. Try `stop()`ing the chain of events each time before you run the animation:

```
$("#button").click(function (e) {
  $(this).stop().css('background', '#03182B').delay(500).queue(function(d) {
    $(this).css('background', '');
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kva4a/)